# UWP VPN - VpnPlugin connect implementation throws exception in StartWithMainTransport

Tags: windows, uwp, vpn

Kindly see the UWP code snippet below tried on Windows 10 desktop using Visual Studio 2017 community edition.

The code implements Custom IVpnPlugin module. When system's VPN configuration is selected to this app and connect is done, the application's task gets triggered and VPN plugin's "Connect()" method gets invoked.

However, following code steps face exception while executing StartWithMainTransport(…). 
("The operation was cancelled by user") on Visual Studio.
On the system's VPN settings following error is seen - "remote access service ip configuration is unusable"

I think I am passing correctly v4 and v6 address to the channel->StartWithMainTransport(…) API which are bound to my m/c network I/f. What other validations may have caused this issue. I do not want to configure certificates etc for the VpnChannel as I plan to implement encapsulate and decapsulate myself in VpnPlugin.

```
// Sample Plugin's connect implementation 
void TunnelPlugin::Connect(Windows::Networking::Vpn::VpnChannel^ channel)
{
    this->dSock = ref new DatagramSocket();
    channel->AssociateTransport(this->dSock, nullptr); // No difference even if this statement is moved after ConnectAsync().
    Platform::String^ svcName = "22111";
    auto result = create_task(dSock->BindServiceNameAsync(svcName));
    result.get();
    // Connect to the destination tunnel address on UDP socket.
    HostName^ remoteTunnelIP = ref new HostName("192.168.1.137");
    Platform::String^ remoteTunnelPort = "22112";
    result = create_task(this->dSock->ConnectAsync(remoteTunnelIP, remoteTunnelPort));
    result.get();

    VpnChannelConfiguration^ chanCfg = channel->Configuration;
    // IP destinations to be routed via VPN
    VpnRouteAssignment^ routeScope = ref new VpnRouteAssignment();
    routeScope->Ipv4InclusionRoutes->Append(ref new VpnRoute(ref new HostName("192.168.1.111"), 32));
    Vector<HostName^>^ localV4Addrs = ref new Vector<HostName^>;
    localV4Addrs->Append(ref new HostName("192.168.1.133")); // Local host name to be bound.
    Vector<HostName^>^ localV6Addrs = ref new Vector<HostName^>;
    localV6Addrs->Append(ref new HostName("fc00::44fd:d3ed:b02a:a05e"));
    Vector<HostName^>^ dnsServers = ref new Vector<HostName^>;
    dnsServers->Append(ref new HostName("1.1.1.1"));
    VpnDomainNameInfo^ dnsInfo = ref new VpnDomainNameInfo(".", VpnDomainNameType::Suffix, dnsServers, ref new Vector<HostName^>);
    VpnDomainNameAssignment^ dnsAssignment = ref new VpnDomainNameAssignment;
    dnsAssignment->DomainNameList->Append(dnsInfo);

    try
    {
        // Throws exception here. 
        channel->StartWithMainTransport(localV4Addrs->GetView(), localV6Addrs->GetView(), nullptr, routeScope, dnsAssignment, 1400, 1412, false, this->dSock);
    }
    catch (Exception^ exc)
    {
        auto type = exc->GetType();
        Platform::String^ str = exc->ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue is now resolved. For some reason the PPP network adapter created for above VPN had IP assigned automatically from 169.254... range. I don't know the reason for same. However, after creating the new VPN configuration, the API worked without any exception.

Comment: If anyone needs sample application code for UWP VPN - refer https://github.com/defaultshr/UWPVPNPluginSample